# How to send Java MimeMultipart via Exchange Server

Tags: jakarta-mail, exchangewebservices

I am using javamail api and I have to send email through Exchange server and then embed image on the email body. How to send embed image in MimeMultipart into EmailMessage using Exchange? I have successfully send the same email using SMTP.

```html
EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
   msg.setSubject(emailSubject);
   msg.getReplyTo().add(emailAdmin);
   msg.getToRecipients().add(emailAddress);

   // This mail has 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image
          MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
          
          //1st part (the message)
          BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          messageBodyPart.setContent(message,"text/html; charset=UTF-8");    
          multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
          
          // second part (the image)
          messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          DataHandler h = null;
          String base64 = configuration.getImageBase64();
    
    //Base64.decodeBase64(string | bytes)    
    byte[] decode = Base64.decodeBase64(base64.getBytes());
    
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decode);
    try {
    h=new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(stream,"application/octet-stream"));
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
    
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(h); 
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "image");
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg; name=image.jpg");
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
    
    // add image to the multipart
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
          
          // put everything together
          msg.setContent(multipart);////how to set multipart into msg?
   
   synchronized (msg) {
    msg.send();
   }
```

Comment: The simplest answer is to configure your Exchange server to allow SMTP so you don't need to use EWS.  If that's not possible, you'll need someone familiar with the EWS APIs to explain how to create attachments using those APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and idea. I found the solution.

Comment: Can you update this question with your own answer?  Thanks.